# Why does my ExtJS 4.2 Label text not change color, though I have a cls applied?

Tags: extjs

I have a label and I'm setting the text color like this, but the label text does not change color:

```
xtype: 'label',
text: 'My Text',
cls: 'myTextClass'
```

Here is the CSS:

```
.myTextClass {
    color: #ff0000;
}​
```

If I do this on the label it works:

```
style: {
    color: '#ff0000'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Look at the label in Google dev tool. Probably your css gets overridden because there is a more specific rule. You have to add something to your css selector like

```
.x-label .myTextClass {
    color: #ff0000;
}​
```

Comment: I guess I'll have to look into the css more. Time to try to find that 'magic' extjs css that works in this case.

Comment: Firebug tells me that label's color is being inherited from div#panel-1139-body.xpanel-body, and I see the color property listed under .x-panel-body-default.

I both of these but neither worked:


.afxPreferenceItemDescription .x-panel-body-default {
    color: #777777;
}​

.x-panel-body-default .afxPreferenceItemDescription {
    color: #777777;
}​